# Catching WM_LBUTTONDOWN on a label?

Tags: c, winapi

For some reason I can't seem to catch the WM_LBUTTONDOWN event on a label ("STATIC" window).  When monitoring with Winspector it appears the message always arrives to the parent window. However, according to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645607(VS.85).aspx), the message should be posted to the Window beneath the cursor.

Does anyknow have an idea why the message does not arrive in the WindowProc function of the label?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the 'Notify' property(SS_NOTIFY) of the label is checked. This means that the label notifies its parent about the mouse events.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760773(VS.85).aspx